# auto trigger list href link one by one

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have list of href with a function called in it,how to auto trigger href link function with parameter i used and pass to JavaScript. I have included my code below.

```
<html>
<head>
 //Add jwplayer script
</head>
<body>
<div id='VideoPlayer'>Loading the player ...</div>
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="show_alert('sample video1','image1')">Test</a>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="show_alert('sample video2','image2')">Test1</a>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert(my_string,s)
{

var playerInstance = jwplayer('VideoPlayer');
playerInstance.setup({
file: my_string,
image: s,
title: 'My Cool Video',
primary: 'html5',
width: 640,
height: 480
});
}
[].forEach.bind(document.querySelectorAll("#myList li a"),function(itm){
itm.click();
})(); </script></body></html>
```

Comment: Try `document.querySelectorAll('#myList a')[0].click()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be as simple as this

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("#myList li a");

for(var i = 0; i < anchors .length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    anchors [i].click();
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: I am getting error anchors[i].click is not a function

Comment: Thanks Bikas,It triggers all list, and loads the last, I want the player to load video and trigger the video one by one...

Comment: Oh I'm very sorry for this. Missed a very basic closure situation here. Should be a simple fix. Let me update my answer

Comment: Again, missed simple closing braces

Comment: Again the player plays the last video, All li tag click is trigger initally then the player starts playing last triggered li function parameter.

Comment: I doubt it has to do with click functionality. Could you check if only one li click is active at a time? I mean, it is possible that new li overrides the previous li click

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below in Jquery:

```
$('#myList li a').each(function(){
  $(this).trigger('click');
});
```